# SQL Job Excel Row Limit on Import

Tags: sql-job

I am able to load about 16,000 rows of data in to a table using my SQL Job. When I try to load more than that, the job fails. I believe it has to do with the buffering limits. I am not the DBA and getting changes are difficult at best. Do I have any options within the SSIS package itself to send all the records in the workbook?

Comment: What is the error CMahler, can we know? Please explain how to reproduce it.

Comment: I changed the way I process this so I do not have the error but to reproduce the error I add one additional record to the excel file and the job fails. I normally need to load between 26k - 83k records but can only send about 16k in batches.

Comment: I still do not know enough to be of help. Certainly there is no limit to the buffer size but there might on the memory available to your process

Comment: I was able to run it today without making any of the adjustments that I need to get it to load so that I can provide the error. The errors are below. I believe the issue is it is timming out opening the file:

Comment: Error: 2019-03-07 14:34:42.12     Code: 0xC0202009     Source: Crystal Excel Source 1 1 [67]     Description: SSIS Error Code DTS_E_OLEDBERROR.  An OLE DB error has occurred. Error code: 0x80004005.  End Error  
Error: 2019-03-07 14:34:42.58     Code: 0xC02020E8     Source: Crystal Excel Source 1 1 [67]     Description: Opening a rowset for "Sheet1$" failed. Check that the object exists in the database.  End Error

Comment: Error: 2019-03-07 14:34:42.58     Code: 0xC004701A     Source: Crystal SSIS.Pipeline     Description: Excel Source 1 1 failed the pre-execute phase and returned error code 0xC02020E8.  End Error  
DTExec: The package execution returned DTSER_FAILURE (1).  Started:  2:34:19 PM  Finished: 2:34:43 PM  Elapsed:  24.422 seconds.  The package execution failed.  The step failed.